# NSURLSession and geocoder errors from too many requests, what is the solution?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsurlsession

Whenever a user searches using my app, it returns an array of up to 100 results. I need to geocode each index(I have the lat and lon at each index), and drop a marker on a map.

I also need to display an https using NSURLSession. I then display each image at the designated marker location. Everything is working "fine" for lower numbers, however I get two significant errors:

1) For the image stuff:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

2) For the geocoder:

```
geoCoder error probably too many requests Optional(Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)")
```

My guess is I am doing too many requests, and apple has a restriction. So how can I get around this? Surely there is a way to do this, or maybe a different method? Here is the code that is displaying the images:

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromUrl(urlString: String) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if let imageData = data as NSData? {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the geocoder:

```
for i in (0 ..< tbc.categorizedArray.count) {

                //make sure that the specified index actually has a geoLon and geoLat
                if var longitude :Double = tbc.categorizedArray[i]["geoLon"] as? Double {
                    longitude = tbc.categorizedArray[i]["geoLon"] as! Double
                    let latitude :Double = tbc.categorizedArray[i]["geoLat"] as! Double

                    //if it does, save it's location
                    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

                    //reverseGeoCode it's location
                    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {
                        placemarks, error in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("geoCoder error probably too many requests \(error)")
                            return
                        }

                        //place the markers
                        if let placemarks = placemarks {
                            let placemark = placemarks[0]
                            // Add annotation
                            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                            annotation.title = tbc.categorizedArray[i]["screenname"] as? String
                            annotation.subtitle = tbc.categorizedArray[i]["userPost"] as? String
                            if let location = placemark.location {
                                annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
                                // Display the annotation
                                self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
                                self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

-9802 is an App Transport Security problem.  Check your cert.

No idea about the geocoder issue.